# How to add new languages to App Summary in iTunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

i want to add more languages to my App Summary in iTunes Connect. Present all details are showing in English . I need to show in different languages. How can i do it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps..

1. Login to iTunes.
2. Select application for which you want to change information.
3. Click on application summary.
4. In Metadata and uploads section. select change another language.
5. You can enter details for your selected languages.

Hope, it will works for you...(Y)

Comment: Thanks dude.. but it showing only one language "English" by default. Also got description like you can add languages only if meta data is editable. I think i cant change it now because now my app is ready for sale. what ever thanks dude once again..

Comment: one more doubt dude .. if my apps meta data is editable, is it possible to add multiple languages at a time??

Comment: Yes man.. You can add multiple languages & it will display store wise. Means suppose you have added English & Spanish, then in U.S store, it will display metadata in English while in Spain, it will display metadata in Spanish. You can make these all changes, when you will go for new version..

Answer (score 2):

After the new revamped iTunes Connect was activated in `September 04, 2014`, the way you can add **language** has changed a bit, so try that :

1. Open **iTunes Connect** and sign in to your account
2. Open `My Apps`
3. Choose the app you want to edit its **languages**
4. You can see the current language beside `Version Information`, click on that language, then a menu will be shown, hover with your mouse over the language you want to add, and a small green `plus` button will appear, click on it .. and the new language will be added

[image]

Comment: this is a limited list, where can I find all the others ?

Comment: @RickyLevi This menu shows all the supported localization, looks like the language you're looking for is not supported